# jQuery element click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element, an anchor, how can I "click it" with jQuery, I mean like a normal user click, because I'm receiving a click on an element..but also I need to fire more events...

Ok here is my example

```
<a class="som" href="http://domain.com/ssl-signup.php" target="_blank">Test Link</a>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.som').click();
});
```

But nothing happens!

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firing the `click` action for an anchor will not redirect the user to the anchor's URL as you would expect with a normal `click`.

Instead, you'll need to do this:

```
$('#anchorId').click(function(){
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

**EDIT -- CORRECT ANSWER BELOW**

I misunderstood the question. To accomplish what you want, just make this call to simulate the `click`:

```
window.location.href = $('#anchorId').attr('href');
```

Comment: It's not working..it's working only if I click the link, doesn't do it automatically

Answer (score 4):

```
$("myelement").click();
```

or

```
$("myelement").trigger("click");
```

Second is useful if you need to decide event type in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).click();
```

Should work.

See: http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click